# Do we say that the $y_i$'s are i.i.d. if $n_iy_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, \theta)$?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, terminology, definition, iid

If $y_i$'s are independent and for given $n_i$,
$$n_iy_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, \theta)$$
Could we say that $y_i$'s are i.i.d.? If not, then what's the proper way to address such problems?

Comment: Welcome to our site! This is an interesting first question and I have added a few more relevant tags. Notice that there's a difference between saying "are defined by the same equation" and "have identical probability distributions".

Answer (score 8):

The $y_i$ are clearly *not* [identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) -- their distribution functions
differ!

For example:

[image]
$\qquad$ $\qquad$ Two scaled binomials with common $p=0.4$.

As you see, those two functions don't coincide, so the distributions are not identical.

As for how you could describe them, you might say the $y_i$ are independent and have a common mean, or that they're independent sample proportions with the same population proportion, or they're independent estimates of the same proportion -- or a number of other things.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The original problem is in a Bayesian textbook and we're supposed to set up a model so that the proportion $y_i$'s are i.i.d. given parameters $\theta_y$. In this case, maybe it's improper to set the model to be $n_iy_i \sim Bin(n_i, \theta_y)$? Then can I model the $y_i$'s with a $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\alpha, \beta$ are hyperparameters? Though it's the former binomial model which actually makes more sense to me.

Comment: It's not the $y_i$ that you model with hyperparameters. Presumably it's $\theta$.